# Styling river charts with TileMill - issue with filling a polygon made of disjoint line segments

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapnik, tilemill, chart

I am trying to style inland river charts produced by the Army Corps of Engineers. I imported the vectors into Postgres, and I’m using TileMill to style the data.

I am having trouble correctly filling the inner contour for the river, because the contour is made of line segments that are broken by features like bridges, and the contour fill spills out.

How can I fill the contour properly and avoid this issue? Some sort of processing in Postgres? Is this a solved problem… a good way to make gapped line segments into polygons for filling?

You can see a screenshot of the issue here:

[image]